# What is up with IP address? Getting bizarre results

Tags: network, dns

I'm trying to limit my teenage son's access to certain websites (like Discord) during school hours only. The only solution I've found is to use something like https://www.dnsfilter.com. They require our public IP.

But while playing with different DNS settings, I'm getting bizarre results for our (dynamic) IP and confused what is causing this.

If I just Google "My IP" I get our true IP.

If I go to any of the "what is my IP" websites (like myip.com) I get different results, like `138.199.9.198`

In Terminal, `curl ifconig.me` and other hosts I get the false IP as well.

Changing the DNS server on the Mac results in different results.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic. This question is about IP addresses on the public internet, and why they might be reported differently by different external tools

Comment: but it's only happening on my Mac

Comment: Changing the DNS server shouldn’t change your Public IP address. How are you connected the internet? Can you run `traceroute ifconfig.me` with different DNS settings and add the output to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your description, it sounds like your Mac is accessing the Internet via a rerouted/controlled connection, such as a Virtual Private Network (VPN).

Please contact [DNSFilter](https://www.dnsfilter.com/contact/) and ask how their product works on Mac and if this is expected.

[138.197.142.28](https://www.lookip.net/ip/138.197.142.28) looks to be operated by [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com). This is a cloud computing service and is probably being used by the DNSFilter service installed on your Mac to route your traffic.

Comment: Turns out it was Surfshark VPN on the router. All sorted!